# Problems while implementing file transfer with sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning Python right now, and try to write a small file transfer program. The following is my codes.

This is the server codes

```
import SocketServer
import commands, time
class MySockServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def recv_all(self,obj, msg_length, des_file):
        while msg_length != 0:
            if msg_length <= 1024:
                print 'here3'
                print msg_length
                print type(msg_length)
                data = obj.recv(msg_length)
                print data
                msg_length = 0
                print 'here4'
                break
            else:
                data = obj.recv(1024)
                msg_length -= 1024
            #print msg_length
            des_file.write(data)
            print 'here4'
        return 'Done'

    def handle(self):
        print 'Got a new conn from', self.client_address
        while True:
            cmd = self.request.recv(1024)#receive data from client
            print cmd
            if not cmd:#deal with ctrl+c from client
                print 'Lost connection'
                break

            CMD = cmd.split()
            print CMD
            option, filename, file_size = CMD[:3]
            print option
            print filename
            print file_size
            if option == 'put':
                #client wants to upload file
                f = file('temp/%s' % filename, 'wb')
                print 'here'
                write_to_file = self.recv_all(self.request, int(file_size), f)
                print 'here1'
                if write_to_file == 'Done':
                    f.close()
                    self.request.send('File uploading done')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = '0.0.0.0'
    p = 9002
    s = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer((h,p),MySockServer)

    s.serve_forever()
```

The client codes:

```
import socket, os

host,port = '192.168.73.11', 9002
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect((host,port))

while True:
    user_input = raw_input('msg to send:: ').strip()
    if len(user_input) == 0: continue
    user_cmd = user_input.split()
    if user_cmd[0] == 'put':
        if len(user_cmd) == 2:
            f = file(user_cmd[1], 'rb')
            f_size = os.path.getsize(user_cmd[1])
            print user_cmd[0], user_cmd[1], str(f_size)
            c.send('%s %s %s ' % (user_cmd[0],user_cmd[1],f_size))
            print 'going to send....'
            c.sendall(f.read())
            print c.recv(1024)
c.close()
```

I just inserted some prints into the codes to find where are the problems. I found that in the recv_all() function in server codes, the sentence 'data = obj.recv(msg_length)' in the 'if' part cannot work, but the sentence in the 'else' part works very well. Is there anyone can tell me why could this happen?

Thanks guys.